# Accessing www.google.com from AS3 flash app

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, cross-domain

In my application, I am trying to display some data from google.com.
My problem is that I always have this error :

```
Error #2048: Security sandbox violation: https://XXXXX.com/runtime.swf cannot load data from http://www.google.com/finance/company_news?q=null:OZG&output=rss.
```

The crossdomain.xml of google looks like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM "http://www.macromedia.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd">
<cross-domain-policy>
  <site-control permitted-cross-domain-policies="by-content-type" />
</cross-domain-policy>
```

And I call the page in my AS3 code like that :

```
var hdr:URLRequestHeader = new URLRequestHeader("Content-type", "text/x-cross-domain-policy");
var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest(feedURL);
request.requestHeaders.push(hdr);
//then load the request with an UrlLoader
```

Do you have any idea of why flash give me this cross damin security error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually misunderstood the meaning of the crossdomain.xml file. Basically, the crossdomain policy file of google doesn't allow any domain.

I think that my only solution is to use a proxy...

Comment: Maybe OP can use AJAX to load the information, and then send it to flash via ExternalInterface?

Comment: I have done a proxy. With Ajax it is often the same problem and you end up doing JSONP etc. I am too lazy deal with those errors ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a PHP proxy, but cURL must be enabled.
For example:

```
$gogle = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($gogle , CURLOPT_URL, $googleurl); 
curl_exec($gogle);
```

If you need further manipulations use the `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` option to return the content as a string instead of outputting it.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER , TRUE); 
$content = curl_exec($ch);
```

use `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` if you need to pass POST agouments (eg: "param=value&q=google")

Comment: I know this possibility, I was looking for something else. Moreover my backend is in Java, so my proxy is in Java and is much more efficient ;)